# Filter Posts from the Main Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, filters, hooks, actions

I want to conditionally merge a custom post type with my posts post type, based on a custom field. If the field's value is 1, then I want I need those custom posts to appear in the same loop as posts on the home page. I can combine the custom post type with the default posts post type, and I can create an array of post IDs to exclude with `post__not_in`, but I can't figure out how to apply that to the main loop. Here's my code for the index.php template below:

```
if (is_home()) {
    $exclude = array();
    $newsQuery = new WP_Query (array(
        "post_type"      => "news",
        "meta_key"       => "post_to_blog",
        "meta_value"     => 1,
        "meta_compare"   => "!=",
        "posts_per_page" => "-1",
    ));
    while ($newsQuery->have_posts()) {
        $newsQuery->the_post();
        array_push($exclude, get_the_ID());
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part("content", get_post_format());
    }
}
if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) {
    echo "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    kriesi_pagination();
    echo "</div>";
}
```

And here's what I'm doing to show the custom post type in the main query in functions.php:

```
function custom_home_loop($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) {
        $query->set("post_type", array("post", "news"));
    }
}
add_filter("pre_get_posts", "custom_home_loop");
```

Is there a way for me to merge these two? I'd like to do something like `$query->set("post__not_in",$exclude);`, but that doesn't work when I try it. No error, the posts just keep showing up. I tried moving the `$exclude` code in to the `custom_home_loop` function, but I keep getting a memory overflow error for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
function custom_home_exclude( $where = '' ) {
    $exclude = array();
    $newsQuery = new WP_Query (array(
        "post_type"      => "news",
        "meta_key"       => "post_to_blog",
        "meta_value"     => 1,
        "meta_compare"   => "!=",
        "posts_per_page" => "-1",
    ));
    while ($newsQuery->have_posts()) {
        $newsQuery->the_post();
        array_push($exclude, get_the_ID());
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    $exclude = join(',', $exclude);
    $where .= " AND `ID` NOT IN ($exclude)";
    return $where;
}


function custom_home_loop($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) {
        $query->set("post_type", array("post", "news"));
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_home_exclude' );
    }
}
add_filter("pre_get_posts", "custom_home_loop");
```

Comment: I get this error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 267386880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /home/bernst0/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 3636`

Comment: This error is not related to Wordpress, it has to do with `php.ini` and `memory_limit` directive. More information is available [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).